# Conditionally rendering different components on same route (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, router, angular-router

I have 2 Separate Views, One For Homepage and Another for Authentication; I want to render `LoginComponent` on route `'/'` and `SignupComponent` on route `'/signup'` If user is NOT Logged in otherwise render components of Homepage. I have tried having 2 Different Router Outlets for Homepage and Auth (But that Shows that the route `'/signup'` is not configured). Here is My Code

- ### app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="logged$ | async; else login">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <!-- ? Primary Outlet -->
</div>
<ng-template #login>
  <router-outlet name="auth"></router-outlet>
  <!-- ? Secondary Outlet for Auth  -->
</ng-template>
```

- ### app.component.ts

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  logged$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.logged$ = store.select('logged');
  }
}
```

- ### app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', children: [/* Homepage Components */] },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    ],
    outlet: 'auth',
  },
];

@NgModule({ ... })
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/better to use guard and redirect to /login?

Comment: I am quite new to Angular (I started yesterday) and Software Development in general (about 4-5 Months), can you please explain a little bit as to what are/how Guards work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of displaying two pages on same URL create a guard. Guard will be called before going to URL, and in this example will redirect you to login if you don't have a token (here we're assuming you have a `AuthService` with `hasAuthToken` method)

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.auth.hasAuthToken()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
```

Routing:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    children: [/* Homepage Components */],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] // Added here
  },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    ],
    outlet: 'auth',
  },
];

@NgModule({ ... })
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```